# get grouping level in agg function

Tags: pandas, dataframe, grouping

I'm looking for a simple reliable way to obtain the grouping level inside an agg function for a pandas groupby object.

So, for example, for the following group object, and agg command:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Name': ['foo', 'bar'] * 3,
                   'Rank': range(6)})
grouped = df.groupby('Name')
result = grouped.agg(GetLevel)
```

What command do I use inside the GetLevel function to return 'foo' and then 'bar'?

```
def GetLevel(arr):
    level = arr.????
    return level
```

Hope that's clear

Comment: What result are you looking for?

Comment: Ultimately, what I want to do is to compare the items in the group with all of the other remaining items in the same column. More specifically, a proportions significance test looking for differences in proportions in survey responses in the group compared to survey responses in all of the other groups (using the R prop.test through rpy2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, this is *not* an answer to my question. Just can't figure how to show code in the comments box.

Anyway, in answer to Andy's question below, here is an example of a function which returns the IndexError message I was talking about:

```
def GetLevel(arr):
    level = arr.iloc[0]['Name']
    colname = arr.name
    return level
```

You'll see it is the same as Roman's function, except with the addition of the colname assignment to arr.name. Strangely, if I remove either one of the two assignments, I get no error, but it just won't work with both. It's like a pointer gets moved or something changes after the first call on arr's attributes.

However, I found that this *does* work:

```
def Getlevel(arr):
    x = arr.index[0]
    colname = arr.name
    level = df.loc[x,'Name']
    return level
```

It's a bit kludgy since I have to insert the name of the dataframe and the aggregation column into the function, which I would prefer to avoid.

Comment: You should edit this to your own question. It could be you have to select an item from names rather than name... (Will take a look later).

Answer (score 0):

Can't say what you want to get, but to get keys inside aggregate function you can take first element from `arr`:

```
>>> def GetLevel(arr):
...     level = arr.iloc[0]['Name']
...     return level
```

Don't know if there's more elegant method to do that. You may also take a look at `grouped.groups`, may be you can take information you need from there.

Comment: Yes, that works, as also does:  level = arr.values[0][0]

But here's the weird thing. Both of these solutions yield errors if I add another call in the function on the the arr attributes. So for instance the following functions fails:

def Getlevel(arr):, e.g. arr.name.

Comment: Sorry, have to rework that last comment, had trouble with the formatting.  As I was saying your solution works, but fails with an IndexError if I add a statement in the function which calls on another arr attribute, like say, **print arr.name**. Somehow, it seems that just accessing an attribute in arr is actually changing it.

Comment: Damn, I can't work out how to enter code in the comments, so I'll have to show you in my 'Answer Your Question' entry below.